# Find N for these sequences with the epsilon-N argument

Tags: analysis

How to find the value of N for these sequences with the epsilon-N argument.

$a_{n}=(1+\frac{1}{n^{3}})^n$

$b_{n}=(-1)^n+(-1)^{n+1}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$

Comment: Those look quite different in their difficulty : the first one converges to $1$ in a not quite obvious way (in terms of finding $N$ as a function of $\epsilon$), but the second one is quite trivial : $N$ is the smaller integer larger than ${\frac{1}{\epsilon}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(b_n)$,

$|b_n|=\frac{1}{n}$ which goes to $0$.

to have $|b_n|<\epsilon$ we need that

$n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and

$N=\lfloor \frac{1}{\epsilon} \rfloor +1$.

Comment: how where u able to show bn = 1/n?

Comment: $(-1)^n+(-1)^{n+1}=0$ !!.

Comment: ups yes ;) smart move

Answer (score 0):

For $a_n$ which is always$>1$, the limit is $1$ and we look for $N$ such that

$n>N \implies 0<a_n-1<\epsilon$.

$log(a_n)=n^2log(1+\frac{1}{n^3})$

but

$x\mapsto log(1+x)-x $  is decreasing
 at $[0,+\infty)$ , so $log(1+x)\leq x$.

and

$log(a_n)\leq \frac{1}{n}$

which yields to

$1<a_n<e^{\frac{1}{n}}$ or

$0<a_n-1<e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1<e^{\frac{1}{n}}$

we can take

$N=max(0,\lfloor \frac{1}{log(\epsilon)}\rfloor+1)$.